# Python - from file create a list find specifics matching types of devices

Tags: python, networking

Need some help on parsing a file. My file to import is similar to below. I want to be able search this file for any specifics "asa, nxos" so that I can write commands to each type of device. For now im looking for the best way to list each line and read it.

In short, I've created a hosts-sticky file that every script will search to pull hosts data. These scripts will go out and gather additional info or make changes to like hosts.

## my file /etc/hosts-sticky

```
-----------------
#Fortigate
10.10.10.4,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,fortigate,fortigate,600d

#CiscoNexus7Ks
10.10.10.5,datacenter-ss-core-2,dc1,prod,cisco,nxos,7018

#CiscoASAFirewalls
10.10.10.1,datacenter-admin-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5580
10.10.10.2,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5525
10.10.10.3,datacenter-ops-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5515
-----------------
```

## Example of what I think i want each line to be...

## My script

```
f = open("/etc/hosts-sticky", "r")
for line in f:
line = f.readline().split()
if line != []:
    print line
```

## Provides a list like...

```
['#Fortigate']
['10.136.25.74,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,fortigate,fortigate,600d']
['#CiscoNexus7Ks']
['10.65.204.27,datacenter-ss-core-2,dc1.prod,cisco,nxos,7018']
['#CiscoASAFirewalls']
['10.65.204.10,datacenter-admin-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5580']
['10.65.248.10,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5525']
['10.65.248.113,datacenter-ops-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5515']
```

## Now I would like to find all the lines with "asa" and return the ip and hostname. I thought something like this would work but it doesnt.

```
f = open("/etc/hosts-sticky", "r")
for line in f:
line = f.readline().split()
if line != []:
    my_hosts = line
    if 'asa' in my_hosts:
        print my_hosts
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change `split()` to `split(",")`, or even better, use the `csv` module.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, it's cleaner to use `if line:` than `if line != []:`... empty lists are falsey.

Comment: Also, you do not need the line `my_hosts = line`, you can just continue `if 'asa' in line`

Comment: Thanks! Im new to this and leaning quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
f = open("/etc/hosts-sticky", "r")
myList=[]
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)
for item in myList:
    if "asa" in item:
        print(item.split(',')[0:2])
```

when used on:

```
-----------------
#Fortigate
10.10.10.4,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,fortigate,fortigate,600d

#CiscoNexus7Ks
10.10.10.5,datacenter-ss-core-2,dc1,prod,cisco,nxos,7018

#CiscoASAFirewalls
10.10.10.1,datacenter-admin-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5580
10.10.10.2,datacenter-fw-2,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5525
10.10.10.3,datacenter-ops-fw-1,dc1,prod,cisco,asa,5515
-----------------
```

outputs the following:

```
['10.10.10.1', 'datacenter-admin-fw-1']
['10.10.10.2', 'datacenter-fw-2']
['10.10.10.3', 'datacenter-ops-fw-1']
```